# Why can't I store True in a Set?

Tags: python, set, boolean

I have this code:

```
mySet = {1,"2",3.0,True}
print("Set: " , mySet)
```

The output is

```
Set:  {1, 3.0, '2'}
```

What happened to the 'True' ?

Comment: `True` is internally the same as `1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `set` save `unique` value one time and `1` and `True == 1` are same. For this reason, you see `1` one time.

```
>>> {1,True}
{1}

>>> {0,False}
{0}

>>> {'1',True}
{'1',True}
```

Comment: That was interesting. The same seems to happen with False and 0